# protein size range for ultrafiltration or nanofiltration

Tags: proteins

I am hoping to concentrate mixed proteins in homogenized leafy vegetables such as kale, spinach etc (after removing pulp and fibers) as a first step in further investigations (second step using size exclusion to isolate frations), but am unsure what pore size is appropriate for ultrafiltration membrane as I do not know the dalton range of the mixture.

Is there a typical range of protein molecular sizes in Daltons found in plant matter?

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Why not do SDS-PAGE and determine the size range?

Comment: Mind that protein isolation goes beyond size exclusion.

Comment: apologies for the abbreviated terms, edited question. I am a chem eng and fairly ignorant about biochemistry laboratory techniques. So, is it sensible to perform electrophoresis on the raw extract to determine the MW range? Can I do that without concentrating and "cleaning up" the raw extract? I was going do that as a later step.